# Probability - Urn with two red and one black balls

Tags: probability

> Consider an urn with two red and one black balls. Draw four times with replacement.
>
> a) What is the probability that exactly one black ball will be drawn?
>
> b) What is the probability that at least one black ball will be drawn?

Here's my answers:

a) Since there are $4$ possible ways to draw exactly one black ball:

```
b r r r     
r b r r     
r r b r     
r r r b
```

Where b stands for black and r for red. If we're drawing with replacement, we have $3^4 = 81$ possible outcomes and hence the probability that exactly one black ball will be drawn $= \dfrac{4}{81}.$

b) With the same approach taken in (a), we would have:

$1$ way of drawing $4$ black balls.

$4$ ways of drawing $3$ black balls and $1$ red one.

$4$ ways of drawing $2$ black balls and $2$ red ones.

$4$ ways of drawing $1$ black ball and $3$ red ones.

Thus the probability that at least one black ball will be drawn $ = \dfrac{13}{81}.$

---

However, my textbook gives (a) $\dfrac{32}{81}$ and (b) $\dfrac{65}{81}$ as solutions. What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: The probability of drawing a black ball on each selection is $1/3$, while the probability of drawing a red ball on each selection is $2/3$.  You have to take these probabilities into account.

Comment: You have to view it as 4 independent experiments in each of which we draw only *one* ball. Then we can multiply the probabilities of the individual events.

Comment: Since the selections are made with replacement, this is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) problem.

Comment: If you are looking for a combinatorial solution, you should take the balls as distinct, not identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly one black ball: we have 4 ways to pick the unique experiment that will have a black ball, as you already noted. In any experiment we have a chance of $\frac{1}{3}$ of a black ball and $\frac{2}{3}$ of a red ball. So any sequence of outcomes like $rrrb$ or $brrr$ has total probability of $\frac{1}{3} \times (\frac{2}{3})^3 = \frac{8}{81}$ and as we have four mutually exclusive such sequences we have $\frac{32}{81}$ for the first as your textbook says.

For "at least one black ball" it's easier to count the complementary event: only red balls. This happens in a unique sequence with chance $(\frac{2}{3})^4 = \frac{16}{81}$. So *our* event happens with chance $$1 - \frac{16}{81} = \frac{65}{81} $$

again as your book says.